# Hibernate Compare PersistentSet with HashSet

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem. In my JUnit test i want to test the insertion in my db done by hibernate. I got an entity which avec a Setlist and i want to see if the list inserted is equals to the list i've set.

```
assertEquals(listDerogationLinux, derogation.getListDerogationLinux());
```

The problem is that hibernate use PersistentSet and i use HashMap so when i try to compare them i got an AassertionError :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.HashSet<[...]> but was: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet<[...]>
```

I've tried a lot a things but the only thing that work is to make a new hashSet with the PersistentSet but it is really ugly ...

```
assertTrue(new HashSet<DerogationLinux>(derogation.getListDerogationLinux()).equals(listDerogationLinux));
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call equals on PersistentSet instead of HashSet. It should work.

`persistentSet.equals(hashSet)`

Comment: Works for me exactly the other way around... That's weird.